# My MVC LINQ code returns AND AND AND :: I would like OR OR OR

Tags: c#, sql, linq

This code at the end of my ActionResult returns rows based on checkboxes that are checked. Looked like it was working until I realized if multiple checkboxes are checked, then only rows having all criteria = true are returned (hence human SQL would have read: WHERE 1=1 AND (AND AND AND).

I am trying to wrap my head around a way to return rows that have searched string and have any one of the checkbox criteria that are checked. (human SQL would be WHERE (1=1) AND (OR OR OR)) .

```
 public ActionResult Index(string searchString, int? searchID, string LastN, bool? bolDWP, bool? bolDEQ, bool? bolOnsiteInstall, bool? bolOnsiteOandM)
    {

   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {

     courses = courses.Where(s => s.CourseTitle.Contains(searchString));       

       if (bolDWP == true)

        {
            courses = courses.Where(s => s.CEUDWP != null);
        }


        if (bolDEQ == true)

        {
            courses = courses.Where(s => s.CEUDEQ != null);
        }

        if (bolOnsiteInstall == true)

        {

            courses = courses.Where(s => s.CEUonsiteInstall != null);

        }



        if (bolOnsiteOandM == true)

        {
            courses = courses.Where(s => s.CEUonsiteOandM != null);
        }

  }

        return View(courses.OrderByDescending(s => s.OESACID));

 }
```

Comment: PredicateBuilder (http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) is your friend.

Comment: I tried being a friend to Predicate Builder but not able to grasp it quickly and it has way too much for just a simple SQL statement. Not sure how LINQ is an improvement to anything.

Comment: You should be careful about writing this type of query, that has multiple different optional clauses. In Sql Server for instance it can often lead to performance issues related to index and/ or query plan caching issues. It is often better to create a stored proc for each combination of the parameters that could come from the search page.